# NotifyOSD does not work

Tags: shortcut-keys, notify-osd

Somehow my NotiyOSD unter 12.04. does not work.

```
notify-send "Test" "Test"
```

produces:

[image: notify-send]

```
notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/status/dialog-warning.png "Test" "Test"
```

produces:

[image: notify-send]

If I use my volume hotkey, I get this:

[image: Hotkey]

But I expect this:

[image: Notyfy-OSD]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `gnome-shell` perhaps?

Comment: Try purging `notification-daemon`: `sudo apt-get purge notification-daemon` then try `apt-get autoremove` Make sure notify-osd is installed: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd`. And restart. Or you could just remove gnome completely..

Comment: No, I am using Terminator. @seth It did not work.

Comment: I cannot see what you expect...  Notyfy-OSD???

Comment: Yes, i expected NotiyOSD. It was looking very pixelated, quite awful. After reinstalling my Ubuntu, NotiyOSD workes as expected: http://paste.dennis-boldt.de/2013/stackoverflow/notify4.png